# Windows Service thread is not stopping in timely fashion in c#

Tags: c#, multithreading, windows-services

I have a windows service which is getting started using Thread.After installation as windows service i am able to start the service properly but as soon as i try to stop the service it is taking too much time and and not getting stopped.I am using `ManualResetEvent` to stop the windows service Here is my code.

```
protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        _thread = new Thread(DoWork);
        _thread.Start();

    }
    private void DoWork()
    {

            while (!_shutdownEvent.WaitOne(0))
            {
                data = new byte[1024];
                int recv = sock.Receive(data);
                stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
            }
            sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
            sock.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception DFGFD)
        {
        }

    }

    protected override void OnStop()
    {
        _shutdownEvent.Set();
        _thread.Join();  // wait for thread to stop
    }
}
```

}

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: What's in your loop? Can it be that the socket shutdown takes long?

Comment: Did you attach a debugger to see what part is causing the trouble?

Comment: @Markus yes it is a socket program which is reading from socket

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You socket is blocking on the receive code. I would suggest issuing:

```
sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sock.Close();
```

in a method called from the `OnStop()` handler (so it is called from another thread to the blocking `Receive`). This will cause the blocking `sock.Receive` to fail with an exception that you can handle by quitting the loop.

Comment: If i am correct is should write sock.Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both);
sock.Close(); codes inside OnStop() method of windows service

Comment: @Pranav: Yes, exactly that.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the code in the `while` is blocking ( ie waiting data from the conenction synchronously )
Typically you shoul use asynchronous I/O operation with the socket, that generally allow you to avoid starting a new thread.

Comment: read some doc, maybe starting from here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bbx2eya8(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in the call to Receive in the loop. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8s4y8aff%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> If no data is available for reading, the Receive method will block
>   until data is available, unless a time-out value was set by using
>   Socket.ReceiveTimeout. If the time-out value was exceeded, the Receive
>   call will throw a SocketException. If you are in non-blocking mode,
>   and there is no data available in the in the protocol stack buffer,
>   the Receive method will complete immediately and throw a
>   SocketException. You can use the Available property to determine if
>   data is available for reading. When Available is non-zero, retry the
>   receive operation.

Therefore, I'd suggest to change the code in the loop to this:

```
if (sock.Available > 0)
{
    data = new byte[1024];
    int recv = sock.Receive(data);
    stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
}
Thread.Sleep(200);
```

This code checks whether data is available for reading and only calls Receive if there is data to read. In order to avoid busy waiting, it issues a call the Thread.Sleep.

If you want to avoid the call to Thread.Sleep, you can specify a ReceiveTimeout on the socket:

```
sock.ReceiveTimeout = 200;
```

The code in the `while` loop would then look like this:

```
try
{
    data = new byte[1024];
    int recv = sock.Receive(data);
    stringData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(data, 0, recv);
}
catch(SocketException ex)
{
    if (ex.SocketErrorCode != SocketError.TimedOut)
        throw;
    // In case of Timeout, do nothing, continue loop
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Problem:**  Receive() is waiting for additional input.

The `Thread.Join()` function is waiting for the thread to finish.

**Possible Solution:**
When I've been in similar situations, I've used a timeout on the Join function `thread.Join(3000);` This gives the thread an opportunity to do a clean shutdown, then continue.